# database maintenance by removing unnecessary information

Tags: mysql

I have a comic website with two databases. first table is to store the comic information (number of the issue, the author and so on). the other table is used to store the links for the pictures of all issues.

Here is a sample

**table_meta**

```
chapter_id    |     chapter_name    |   chapter_author 
   123        |       whatever!!    |      someone     
   987        |       whatever!!2   |      someone
```

**table_pictures**

```
chapter_id    |     picture_num    |   picture_ext
   123        |       001          |      jpg
   123        |       002          |      jpg
```

as you can see `chapter_id` 987 does not have anything in the `table_pictures` table. I want a mysql query that delete all this unnecessary information. Here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_meta`
LEFT JOIN `table_pictures` ON table_meta.chapter_id = table_pictures.chapter_id
```

This will link the two databases together. but how can I delete anything that is not linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example how to negate your `LEFT JOIN` and use it for deleting the data in `table_meta`:

```
DELETE table_meta
FROM table_meta
LEFT JOIN table_pictures ON table_meta.chapter_id = table_pictures.chapter_id
WHERE ISNULL(table_pictures.chapter_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do a `LEFT JOIN` it's possible that the joined table will have `NULL` for all data:

```
SELECT ... WHERE table_pictures.chapter_id IS NULL
```

So you can do this to find all those where the link doesn't work, or as an inverse, `RIGHT JOIN` and select all those not in the list with a `WHERE ... NOT IN (SELECT ...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table_meta WHERE chapter_id NOT IN(
    SELECT chapter_id FROM table_pictures 
      WHERE table_meta.chapter_id = table_pictures.chapter_id
);
```